# Putextras not working

Tags: java, android

I have multiple variables to pass from one activity to another.

I have this in the first activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.bStartGame:
    Intent i = new Intent(StartScreen.this, GameScreen.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("Name 0", sName0);
    extras.putString("Name 1", sName1);
    extras.putString("Name 2", sName2);
            .
            .
            .
    i.putExtras(extras);
    StartScreen.this.startActivity(i);
    finish();
    break;
```

In the second activity, I have this:

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
 Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
 String name0 = extras.getString("Name 0");

 TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTEST);
 test.setText(name0);
```

However, the textview shows nothing when I do this. How can I fix this?

EDIT: In the first activity I have:

```
 name0 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName0);
 sName0 = name0.getText().toString();
```

and the same for all the other names with their relevant references.

Also, just for clarification, name0 is the edittext, sName0 is the string and "Name 0" is the key.

Comment: have you tried it sending key without space as `extras.putString("Name1", sName0);`

Comment: `In the second activity, I have this:` Where in the second activity is that code?

Comment: Have you double checked the value of `name0`? The problem could be with your layout instead...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong in the code you've shown.

```
String name0 = extras.getString("Name 1");
```

`name0` here has the correct value: `""`.  If it was not sending the extras properly, it would be `null`, and would give you a `NullPointerException` on `.setText()`.

```
extras.putString("Name 1", sName0);
extras.putString("Name 1", sName1);
```

Here, you're overwriting `"Name 1"` with the value of `sName1`, which is probably blank. I'd assume that you want to send `sName0` instead.

Comment: sorry the first "Name 1" is supposed to be "Name 0"

Comment: Regardless of that, did you check the value of `sName1`? It's being sent as blank.

Comment: I've filled both name0 and name1 in, which should fill sName0 and sName1 but nothing is still showing on the textview

Comment: You're calling `sName0 = name0.getText().toString();` outside of `onClick`. Don't do this--you need to fetch that value in the `onClick` method.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have shown sNameXX have not been declared or initialised. You send them to the other Activity correctly.